# Unable to create instance of a class with empty constructor

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have written the following code for Set class in C++. The issue I am facing is 
When I am doing  `Set *set = new Set();` in the main method. It's showing the error - 
`argument list for class template "Set" is missingC/C++(441)` 
That means it's looking for the constructor with arguments. Even though a constructor without
argument is specified. What could be the reason for this ?

The other error I am getting is at `template <class ItemType> Node<ItemType> *Set<ItemType>:: getPointerTo(const ItemType &target) const` line.
Error : `declaration is incompatible with`
This can be seen as declared in the Set class inside private. Although it's declared exactly the 
same in the Set class and the implementation class. I am not sure why it's throwing that error

```
    #include "Set.h"
        #include "Node.h"
        
    template <class ItemType>
    Set<ItemType>::Set() : headPtr(nullptr), itemCount(0)
    {
    } // end default constructor
    
    template <class ItemType>
    Set<ItemType>::Set(const Set<ItemType> &item)
    {
        itemCount = item->itemCount;
        Node<ItemType> *origChainPtr = item->headPtr if (origChainPtr == nullptr)
                                           headPtr = nullptr; // Original bag is empty; so is copy
        
    } // end copy constructor

template <class ItemType>
Node<ItemType> *Set<ItemType>::
    getPointerTo(const ItemType &target) const
{
    bool found = false;
    Node<ItemType> *curPtr = headPtr;
    while (!found && (curPtr != nullptr))
    {
        if (target == curPtr->getItem())
            found = true;
        else
            curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
    } // end while
    return curPtr;
} // end getPointerT
```

```
template <class ItemType>
class Set : public SetInterface<ItemType>
{
private:
    Node<ItemType> *headPtr;
    int itemCount;
    Node<ItemType> *getPointerTo(const ItemType &target) const;

public:
    Set();
    Set(const Set<ItemType> &item); // Copy constructor
};                                  // end LinkedBag
```

```
#include <iostream>
    #include "Set.h"
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
    
        Set *set = new Set();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `Set` seems to be a template, not a type. You cannot create an object of a template.

Comment: Did you mean to do something like `Set<int> *set = new Set<int>();`. Or probably even better `Set<int> set;`. Using `new` and `delete` are usually a last-resort. Normally you don't need it at all in c++.

Comment: @super  `Set<int> *_set = new Set<int>();` This seems to work. Probably I was not specifying the value of template so it was throwing an error

Comment: @DanielLangr As I mentioned in the previous comment that approach worked. But I want to understand your point. Because I have declared `template <class ItemType>
class Set : public SetInterface<ItemType>` Doesn't that make Set a class. Or you were saying the same thing that I have to pass in template type in Set ?

Comment: Also any ideas why I am getting error when I implement the method - `getPointerTo`

Comment: `Set` is not a class, but a class template. Class:class-template :: cookie:cookie-cutter.

Comment: @puneeta `template <class ItemType> class Set` means that `Set` is a template. `: public SetInterface<ItemType>` that an instantiation of `Set` inherits from an instantiation of `SetInterface` with the same type argument; `Set<int>` inherits from `SetInterface<int>`.

Comment: @molbdnilo So if it's a template that means I cannot instantiate it ? I am planning to implement Sets using a linked list. And I want to create a generic Set. So like my set could be initialized like `Set<int> set = new Set<int>()` or `Set<string> set = new Set<string>()` I am getting a feeling now I am making it overcomplicated and approach is not proper

Comment: But I saw this type of declaration of class set with template above in a book. I am wondering what could be the reason for making Set a template. Is there any good reason to do it ?

Comment: What's your view about using `NULL` and `nullptr`. Are there any pros and cons ? Or we could use it anywhere

Comment: @puneeta Class template is a template and you cannot make an object of a template. You first need to _instantiate_ template to its entity, that is, instantiate a class template into a class in your case. Once you have that class, you can create its objects (instances). Bottom line: an instance of a class template is a class, an instance of a class is an object.

Comment: BTW, sometimes, you may omit template arguments, if they can be _deduced_ for you. This, since C++17, works even for class templates, but only under special circumstances. Basically, the template arguments need to be derived from the constructor calls, namely, from its function arguments (similarly as with function template argument deduction works). Such you can write `std::pair p(1.0, 1);` even if `std::pair` is a class template: https://godbolt.org/z/eeEYP9xMo. Your default constructor has no arguments, so, there cannot be any deduction applied.

Comment: As for the second problem, I cannot reproduce it: https://godbolt.org/z/1xxrKxnq3. You should prepare complete **minimal** reproducible self-comilable example and specify your build configuration, such as a compiler, OS, flags,... Note that you should primarily ask only one question per question on this site, especially when they are not related. I would suggest to create a new separate question for that problem.

Comment: @DanielLangr what my understanding is if I want to create a generic set. Like a set that could store int or string etc. Then I need to declare template <class T> on top of it. Is that correct ? Also so suppose now I have a template for the set as mentioned in the post. How do I instantiate it to make it a class ?

Comment: @puneeta You "force" template instantiation by providing template arguments. `Set` is a class template, but once you write `Set<int>` or `Set<std::string>`, a compiler will instantiate `Set` into these two classes. Note that these classes are different and unrelated types.